# Detect duplicate records using Sequel and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I want to check to see if the email address that a new person uses when registering is a duplicate of an existing record.

Here is the code:

```
post '/signup' do
    email_address = params['email_address']
    username = params['username']
    password = params['password']
    @duplicate = DB[:users].select(:email_address).where('email_address = ?', email_address)
    if email_address = @duplicate
        redirect "/?msg=Email address already in use. Try again"
        return
    end
end
```

This blocks all attempts even when the email address is not a duplicate and redirects with the error message.

If I substitute `@duplicate` with `duplicate` (without the @ mark) then same result, all attempts blocked. If I use `==` instead of `=` then duplicate email addresses are ignored and no attempts are blocked.

I know the query:

```
DB[:users].select(:email_address).where('email_address = ?', email_address)
```

is correct because I have tested it. So I assume the problem lies with the construction of the if clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `email_address = @duplicate` the code inside the `if` will be always excuted since the condition for the `if` expression is always true. Anything in Ruby except `nil` and `false` evaluates as `true` in boolean context.

If you write `email_address == @duplicate` the code inside the `if` will be never executed since you are trying to compare 
a string (`email_address`) with an object of class `Sequel::Postgres::Dataset` (`@duplicate`).

A better approach could be

```
post '/signup' do
    # same code as yours...
    @duplicate = DB[:users].where(email_address: email_address).count
    unless @duplicate.zero?
      # redirect and return
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both your solutions. I believe that I can generalize from here, in addition to solving my immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

You  need add .first at the end of you query otherwise you will get an array.

After that you can test if @duplicate != nil

Comment: thanks, works. "nil" is new to me. The statement seems to mean if no result (i.e. no duplicate) then redirect .. which is the opposite of what I intend. If there is a 0 result then there is no duplicate so proceed. ?? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: nil == NULL it's mean you have no result